# How this scrollbar bug in Chrome solved on stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scrollbar

If I apply this code:

```
var the_doc=document.documentElement;
var old_element = the_doc;
var new_element = the_doc.cloneNode(true);
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
```

in clean page like this:

```
`<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        _<br>
        _<br>
        _<br>
        ...
        _<br>
    </body>
</html>`
```

the scroll handler in Chrome (ver  60.0.3112.90 from 2 August 2017) visually doesn't moves, but works and blinking.
It seems like bug of chrome (in Firefox it's all right).

But if I apply this code in Chrome-console at stackoverflow.com page, everything is ok. Even in Chrome!

How stackoverflow site solve this issue?